# Excel - Stacked Scatter Plot - digital signal timing

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to graph digital signals on a graph to show the timing breakout of each. Everyone except one signal is going to be a 1 or a 0. There is an additional that can be an integer, it would be nice to be able to show that one too on the same graph. However, i want them all to be on separate axis on the same chart. I want it to look like the attached picture. The program i am using shows a small time slice of the actual data recorded, and spits out multiple excel spreadsheets for every 30000 samples or so. So what you'll see in the picture is only handy for a few minutes of recording.

[image]

Comment: What does the data look like when it is in spreadsheet format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know Excel doesn't have such a native plot. Some workarounds:

- You could bias each signal around a multiple of 2, then hide the y-axis.
- You can stack multiple charts in a sheet and plot each signal seperately. You can format the first chart to the right "slim" formatting then copy and paste the chart multiple times. Then click each chart line and drag the highlighted signal column over to the next signal.
- Advanced but overkill solution: code VBA macro to create shapes and lines to look like your sample graph.
- Use Origin?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a constant to each set of data, so the first one goes from 0 to 1, the second from 1 to 2, etc. Or maybe 0 to 1, 1.1 to 2.1, 2.2 to 3.2, etc., to give a small separation between lines.

Plot them all together and hide the horizontal gridlines and Y-axis.